# Can JavaScript communicate to a different server?

Tags: javascript, ajax, client-server, client-side

Can JavaScript interact with a database that lives on a different server?

I.e. there are three computers involved

- A server : which gives an HTML page with JavaScript to
- A client : which runs that page which wants to talk to
- A second server : which sends and receives data to/from the client

Does this violate the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)? If not why not? If so is there a way around it?

My background - I'm a competent computer scientist but I've never dealt with client side programming. While answering feel free to use complex ideas but please assume I know nothing about the JavaScript language or the specific policies in place behind client-side programming.

Comment: Yep, it can. See the `$.getJSON` jquery implementation as an example: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/ajax.js#L284

Comment: @MRocklin it's a standard comment to anyone below ~60-70% accept and is an indication you ought to go back and accept answers that helped as people are more likely to help you in future.

Comment: @MRocklin This is not about the question. This was a comment about how is he not trying to answer your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does violate Same Origin whenever your html comes from server 1 and AJAX requests go to server 2.

Check out [Cross Origin Resource Sharing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing). It is a standard designed to handle exactly this
situation. It is implemented in most modern browsers.

Alternatively you can use [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) to serve the data, or if you have no control of the second server, use a reverse proxy to proxy requests to the second server through the first.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this violates the SOP. There are ways round it, but it's worth underlining a key point:

**Any attempt from the client to access a remote server requires complicity on the part of that server.**

So what are the options?

**JSON-P**

JSON-P involves having the server return a response wrapped in an invocation to a callback function. It works like this:

- a new script tag is DOM-scripted into the page, or an existing one is
  reused
- the script tag's `src` attribute is set as the request path (script tags can load scripts from anywhere - they are not subject to
  the SOP)
- the server response with data, often (but not necessarily)    encoded
  as JSON, and prints this out as an argument to an invocation    of a
  callback function (which must be defined in your JS)

So a JSON-P request, written in native JS, looks like this:

```
callback = function(response) { console.log(response); };
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = 'http://www.some-request.com/here.php?callback=callback'; //the example happens to use the same name; the callback parameter tells the some-request domain what function to wrap JSON in 
document.body.appendChild(script);
```

Then, if the server's response was

```
callback({"foo": "bar"});
```

...we'd get the response in our console. Note I explicitly make the function global because it must be accessible and not hidden by scope. (In this sense it must be globally *accessible*, but not necessarily global in the traditional sense - it could, for example, be a static method of a global namespace).

Many JSON-P-complying web servers allow you to stipulate the name of the function you want it to call, normally by appending this info to the request URL via `&callback=func_name`.

More info on this [here](http://www.mitya.co.uk/blog/2012/Mar/JSON-P-what-what-s-not-and-how-works-205).

**CORS / XHR2**

In CORS, aka the cross-domain idea behind XHR (i.e. AJAX) v2, this will mean the server sending a  header signifying which domains may make cross-domain requests to it - or all domains. In PHP, for example, we could allow any caller domain to make the request thus:

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
```

More info on this [here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/xhr2/).

**EasyXDM***

[EasyXDM](http://easyxdm.net/wp/2010/03/17/sending-and-receiving-messages/) collates a number of vendor-specific and newer, HTML5-arriving means of posting and receiving text-based messages between domains, and is worth a look.

**Non-JS**

If you need to get something from a server that does not play ball, your only option is an intermediary server-side script, as these can fire cURL requests that can scrape a remote resource without the confines of the SOP.

```
$curl = curl_init("http://www.example.com/");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response = curl_exec($curl);
```

More on cURL [here](https://www.php.net/curl).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this violates the same-origin policy.

You can get around this limitation by using [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP), which leverages the behavior of the `script` tag to grab data from the second (database) host. This assumes that you can serve data from the second host in a very particular way: wrapping a JSON response in a callback. It also requires using GET to serve the responses.

An alternative is [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing), which will also require some control over how the server is sending data, and will limit you to more recent web browsers.